# Should Elasticsearch tasks be deleted after their completion?

Tags: elasticsearch

After asynchronous remote reindexing, there are plenty of completed tasks that I haven't deleted.
Are there some concerns because there are around 100 or more completed tasks? (ES v7.x)

Usually, I don't delete them. Only if there is some issue or it seems like it's pending for some time, then I cancel it, otherwise, I leave them.
The question is primarily for a better understanding of ES and its concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete them when done unless you need/want some historical tracking.

They serve no other use than for your own consultation.